# How to PIN TabLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-support-library

I want set my animated ImageView like background for all AppBarLayout. But I can't set app:layout_collapseMode="pin" in TabLayout.
Example expanded: [ExpandedAppBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOc07.png);
Example collapsed: [CollapsedAppBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W91eD.png).
My code (PanningView extends ImageView):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">
    <com.peter.press.widget.panningView.PanningView xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/panningView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        custom:panningDurationInMs="@integer/panning_view_fade_duration"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|exitUntilCollapsed"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/test" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "you can't set it"? What are expecting, and what happens?

Comment: @lenz , i set:  app:layout_collapseMode="pin" , but TabLayout not fixed as in screen "CollapsedAppBar".

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?